# Limit of an integral (SEEMOUS 2014 problem 4)

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

Please show me how to solve this problem.
 I tried to make the substitution $x/n=y$ but I don't know how to go further.

> **(a)** Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^n\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{n}}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
>
> **(b)** Find the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(n\int_0^n\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{n}}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: May you write down your question directly in your post? Someone might be not willing to, or have internet problem with linking to the image.

Comment: I don't know how to write in Latex.

Comment: It takes a couple of minutes to learn and quite frankly I think it's a bit rude to expect people to help you when you haven't put in effort to help them.

Comment: Some tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720872/why-is-lim-n-to-infty-n-arctan-fracxn-x and the rest should be easy.

Answer (score 11):

About the first integral, we have
$$ \int_{n}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
and for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{n}}{\frac{x}{n}}=1 $$
hence by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{n}}{\frac{x}{n}}\cdot\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
In a similar way, since in a right neighbourhood of the origin we have
$$ \frac{\arctan x}{x} = 1-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{5}-\ldots $$
the second limit equals
$$ -1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\color{red}{-\frac{\pi+2}{4}}.$$
Explanation:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\left(\int_{0}^{n}\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{n}}{\frac{x}{n}}\cdot\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)&=&\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\left(\int_{0}^{n}\left(\frac{\arctan\frac{x}{n}}{\frac{x}{n}}-1\right)\cdot\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\arctan\frac{1}{n}\right)\\&=&-1+\lim_{n\to +\infty}n^2\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}-1\right)\cdot\frac{dx}{1+n^2 x^2}\\&=&-1+\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}-1\right)\cdot\frac{dx}{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}\\(DCT)\quad &=& -1+\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}-1\right)\frac{dx}{x^2}\\(Taylor)\quad&=&-1+\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n-2}}{2n+1}\,dx\\&=&-1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)\\&=&-1+\frac{1}{2}\left[-\arctan(1)-\left(\arctan(1)-1\right)\right]\\&=&-\arctan(1)-\frac{1}{2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you.This is the only solution?

Comment: I guess there are plenty of equivalent alternatives, as usual, but it looks to me that the DCT provides an efficient way.

Comment: Anyway, I would be glad to see the downvoter explain his downvote.

Comment: Since this problem does not have an official solution yet, I do not think it is a bad idea to have a complete solution here on MSE.